# Flutter channel used and going from mainActivity to another activity and show android view then can back to flutter view

Tags: flutter

Its java class when we come to flutter. I am calling the next activity UI. So how can I call back to flutter class again this activity?

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity   {
        final String CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper";

        @Override
        public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine){
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);


            new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).
                    setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                                if(call.method.equals("showNativeView")){

                                    Intent intent= new  Intent(MainActivity.this, Camera.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else{
                                    result.notImplemented();
                                }

                            }
                    );


        }
    }
```